# Codeigniter form, redirect page on submit

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, search

I have created a search form that I want to forward on submit.

The way it should work is the user enters the term/keyword they want to search for, the form will then forward them to **/search/$keyword**

My research has let me to the conclusion that the form needs to be posted to the controller then do the forwarding from there. But I have tried numerous times and can't get it to forward.

Here is the form:

```
<?php echo form_open('search'); ?>
            <input id="search_text" name="searchquery" type="text" value="enter your search here..." onfocus="if(this.value == 'enter your search here...') this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value == '') this.value='enter your search here...';" maxlength="120" >
       <?php echo form_close();?>
```

And the controller:

```
if($this->input->post('searchquery')){
 redirect('search', $this->input->post('searchquery'));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change this line:

```
redirect('search', $this->input->post('searchquery'));
```

to:

```
redirect('search/' . $this->input->post('searchquery'));
```

---

In your redirect call, the second parameter is the "method" of redirection, so that's why your redirect is not working. what you want is something like this:

```
redirect('search/my+search+term');
```

That's why we do the string concatenation, instead of passing the search term to the second parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead.

```
if($this->input->post('searchquery')){
 redirect('search/'.$this->input->post('searchquery'));
}
```

You were using the redirect method incorrectly. Here's an excerpt from the documentation.

> The optional second parameter allows you to choose between the
>   "location" method (default) or the "refresh" method. Location is
>   faster, but on Windows servers it can sometimes be a problem